# run expensive computation in another thread in blender

Tags: python, blender

I'm developing a blender operator that needs to run an expensive for loop to generate a procedural animation. It looks roughly like this:

```
class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    def execute(self, context):
        data = []
        for _ in range(10000):
            data.append(run_something_expensive())
        instantiate_data_into_blender(data)
        return {"FINISHED"}
```

The problem of course is that when I run it from blender it takes a lot of time to finish and the UI becomes unresponsive. What is the recommended way to handle this? Is there a way to run this computation in another thread and potentially update the blender scene as the results get generated? (i.e. running `instantiate_data_into_blender` every once in a while as data becomes available)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the asyncio module.

First: you have to import asyncio and define a loop.

```
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

Second: you create an async method in your operator.

```
async def massive_work(self, param):
        returnedData = await your.longrun.func(param)
        if returnedData == '':
            return False

        return True
```

Third: call the async method from your execute method

```
allDone = loop.run_until_complete(massive_work(dataToWorkOn))
if allDone != True:
     self.report({'ERROR'}, "something went wrong!")
     return {'CANCELLED'}
else:
     self.report({'INFO'}, "all done!")
     return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: do you have a minimal code example in blender? I'm aware of the asyncio module in regular python, but I don't know how that would work inside a blender operator.

Comment: @MeiZhang I hope this works and I didn't forget to copy something needed. your.longrun.func() was a socket related method...